# Linear approximation of a stable manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Given 
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = -x + y^2\\
\dot{y} = x - 2y +y^2
\end{cases}
$$

Find a linear approximation of the STABLE manifold for the equilibrium $(1,1)$.

**My attempt:** By using the Principle of Linearized Stability, since $(1,1)$ is a hyperbolic equilibrium, $Df((1,1))$ has $2$ eigenvalues: $-2$ and $1$. This means $(1,1)$ is an unstable saddle, so only the $y$-axis is a stable manifold at $(1,1)$, based on the phase portrait of Andronov–Hopf bifurcation at unstable saddle equilibrium $(1,1)$.

**My question:** I find my answer kinda weird, so I just wonder if that's correct? If not, how are we supposed to find a stable manifold at an unstable equilibrium?

Comment: Could you write down $Df((1,1))$? Is $(0,1)^T$ really the eigenvector for eigenvalue $1$?

Comment: @LutzL: Df((1,1)) = (-1 2, 1 0) (Matlab notation here) => The eigenvector corresponds to eigenvalue $1$ is $(1,1)$, but this manifold is UNSTABLE (by the global stable/unstable manifold theorem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you linearize, you are approximating your system by the first order terms around the equilibrium or, in matricial form:
$$
\dot x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\,
(x-x_0)
$$

Now recall that the real meaning of finding eigenvalues is performing a change of basis. The matrix of eigenvectors is:
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
so that means that your diagonal form is expressed in a new coordinates $z$ related to the older by the change of basis $x=B z$, or $z=B^{-1} x$, or:
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_1 &= -x + y \\
z_2 &= x+2y
\end{aligned}
$$

(NOTE: if you substitute this change on the linearized equation, you obtain the uncoupled system
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot z_1 &= -2 z_1 \\
\dot z_2 &= z_2
\end{aligned}
$$
which can be solved as $z_1=k e^{-2 t}$, again showing that if you could restrict your space to the stable manifold, the system would be stable)

The equilibrium $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is moved to $z=(0,3)$, so you have the two linear subspaces:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &= -x + y \\
3 &= x+2y
\end{aligned}
$$
Since the first one corresponds to the negative eigenvalue, the stable subspace is:
$$
x = y
$$

Comment: How can $x=y$ be a STABLE subspace?? Since $x=y$ goes through the point $(1,1)$, which is hyperbolic in this case, but this point is clearly unstable for the linearized equation. In fact, the previous part of this problem asks to show the set $U=\left\{(x,y): x=y, x>0\right\}$ is an UNSTABLE manifold for $(1,1)$, which is easy by the theorem of global stable/unstable manifold.

Comment: @user177196 If you were able to set your initial point just on the stable manifold, then your trajectory would converge to the fixed point. The problem is that the system is nonlinear, so you will never see this behaviour in numerical simulations.

Comment: I understand what you said, but in this case, $(1,1)$ is not stable, as well as its corresponding subspace $x=y$. Did I miss something here??

Comment: @user177196 For an equilibrium to be stable, trajectories must converge to the point starting from *any* point in a neighbourhood. Now, for each positive eigenvalue, there is a direction that contains initial values of trajectories that escape from the fixed point, so there is instability. Think about the stable manifold as trying to put a pen standing on the tip: in theory, if you were able to perfectly balance it, you could leave it stable, in practice it is impossible.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your patience and effort in trying to help me understand. So you're saying that the linear approximation of the STABLE manifold is $x=y$? But i still don't think this one is stable:P

Comment: I do not get what is troubling you: the "stable manifold" is called that way, it is a definition. There is no such property as to say that a manifold *is* stable.

Comment: @user177196 Miguel is right. This manifold is stable. From the original equations (nonlinear system) note that $\frac{d(x-y)}{dt}=-2(x-y)$ which is certainly stable.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia: can you please help find the equilibrium point that makes $U=\left\{(x,y): x=y, x>0\right\}$ an unstable manifold? I found that point as $(1,1)$ but based on your solution, I think that was wrong:P

Comment: @CTNT: can you please help find the equilibrium point that makes $U=\left\{(x,y): x=y, x>0\right\}$ an unstable manifold?

Comment: @user177196 The manifold $U_0=\{(x,y):x=y\}$ is stable in the sense that all trajectories converge towards $U_0$. In $U_0$ the dynamics is reduced to $\dot{x}=x(x-1)$. Thus, there are two equilibrium points within $U_0$ the $(0,0)$ and the $(1,1)$. From $\dot{x}=x(x-1)$ one can see that $\dot{x}>0$ if $x<0$, $\dot{x}<0$ if $x\in(0,1)$ and $\dot{x}>0$ if $x>1$. Thus $(0,0)$ is a stable equilibrium in $U_0$ whereas $(1,1)$ is an unstable equilibrium in $U_0$.

Comment: @CTNT: But isn't $(1,1)$ unstable in $U_0$ implies that $U_0$ is unstable manifold at $(1,1)$? This is what confused me the most:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jacobain matrix $A$

$$
A = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2y \\
1 & -2+2y
\end{bmatrix}_{x=y=1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now the linear approximation system is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{y}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Or 
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= -x + 2y \\
\dot{y} &= x
\end{align}
$$